# Funds received still shows pending and unavailable until confirmed in Exodus. Should I be concerned?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, synchronization, exodus

I have a transaction I received in my account that has been marked as pending for the last 12 hours (now 16) and counting. The BTC and US equivalent shows in my wallet (Exodus) but  the wallet has it pending and states its unavailable until confirmed. This has me a bit worried that I will not receive my funds, even though when I check the transaction ID on BlockChair it shows 77 (now 102) confirmations.  This is first time a transaction has taken so long, the most time it took in the past was more or less 30 minutes.  Thanks in advance for educating me on the subject.

Comment: Exodus says it's pending?

Comment: Did you get your funds? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

> **This has me a bit worried that I will not receive my funds, even though the blockchain shows 77 confirmations.**

The blockchain is the only truth. Those funds have been received long ago.

---

The only question is why your wallet isn't showing it.

There are many possible reasons, some are

- your wallet is a "custodial wallet" owned by some corporation  - you need to talk to the business involved
- your wallet is a "full-node" type of "custodial" wallet - you need to check if it has fully synchronised.
- there is some other problem with your wallet.
- you have been tricked by a scammer.

For more precise help, you could edit your question to include details of the name and type of wallet and some general description of where the transaction came from (a friend? a customer? an investment manager?)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on what the issues may be.  I am wondering now if it may be latter. Can you explain further how the scam could happen since the blockchain should be eliminating these types of fraudulent acts.  I am not very educated on the subject so I appreciate your time.  I am actually updating the wallet as I type, hopefully the update will show the update complete and eliminate my anxiety.

Comment: @Sherrie: There are many different ways fraudsters can trick people. You could look at [examples here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraud). If someone you met online set up the wallet, or said they were mining or doubling your bitcoins etc, it would probably be a scam. However it may just be a temporary problem with your wallet - hard to say without more information.

Comment: @Sherrie: Exodus seems to be a reasonable choice for a wallet. You should make sure you have a written note of your recovery phrase in a safe place (not on a computer or phone).  If you bought Bitcoin using the built-in exchange, you should probably ask Exodus for help with your problem.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I updated and restarted Exodus and I am no longer seeing the pending message, so I am feeling very relieved!!  Thank you for your responding and sharing